# Replaced ceiling light with a ceiling fan and light, then added a remote control

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

I replaced an existing ceiling light with a fan/light combo, and then added a remote control.  The fan and light work, but the light only seems to have partial power as the light is very dim.  What is wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't exchange the two channels? If you were running the light off a fan circuit set to "slow" you might get that effect.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of both boxes?

Comment: I figured it out.  It's wired right.  The remote I have, the button for the light is a dimmer.  I wasn't holding it down to brighten the light.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  The only other thing is that the fan only runs on slow.  I think I saw somewhere that it was to be on high before hooking up the remote.  Does that mean I need to unhook remote, turn fan on high, then hook the remote back up?

Comment: Sounds like you need to read the installation and user manual carefully. That remote may have all sorts of "hidden" features.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and mark it as such. Answered questions (even answering your own) are useful!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, this site is new to me. I got the ceiling fan and light working correctly with the remote I installed. Turns out that I had it wired correctly and just didn't realize I had to hold down the light button on remote control to increase the light brightness. I also figured out all I had to do to get the fan speeds working was to have the fan on high first,  then the low, medium, and high settings worked on the remote. And this was without having to disconnect the remote. Also,  the universal remote control I purchased did not come with  an installation user's manual 
Thank you all for your kind and patient help and support!